# awk: Set value in second line, colunm (if it exists) to variable

Tags: command-line, awk

Consider this file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat > example_file.txt <<EOL
group, value
1, 3.21
1, 3.42
1, 3.5
2, 4.1
2, 4.2
EOL
```

Now I want to set **the value in the second column, second row** to a variable `val2`. I try:

```
var='example_file.txt' 
cat $var | val2=$(awk -F, "NR==2{print $2; exit}")
```

but

- This doesn't work: `echo "$val2"` returns nothing
- I would like to assign to `val2` a default value in case the file has only one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var='example_file.txt' 
val2=$(cat $var | awk -F, "NR==2{print $2; exit}")
```

The cat needs to be directly piped into the awk command, rather than the variable assignment line.

Note that you can get rid of the `cat` all together with:

```
val2=$(awk -F, "NR==2{print $2; exit}" <$var)
```

Comment: Thanks! I still get the whole second line when I do `echo "$val2"
` (I need only the value in the second column, e.g `3.21` instead of `1, 3.21`)

Comment: The awk expression probably needs to be in single quotes rather than double quotes to prevent the shell expanding it to its second positional parameter (which, if empty, would result in `NR==2 {print }`, explaining why you get the whole line)